# PLINQ + LINQ = NRE?

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception, plinq

What is the reason for random NREs when running the code below? Given that `results` is initialized how is it possible to get `t` within lambda as `null`?

```
var results = new List<Result>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Parallel.For((index) =>
        {
            results.Add(Result.Create(...));    
        });

    results = results.Where(t => t.IsValid).ToList(); // NRE here due to t is null!

}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't compile and is wrong. there is a `Parallel.For` without a collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<>` isn't thread safe. You are adding elements from multiple threads. If you really want to use it:

```
lock (results)
{
    results.Add(Result.Create(...));
}
```

Note that your example is wrong... Something that compiles and runs would be:

```
var results = new List<Result>();

Parallel.For(0, 100, index =>
{
    lock (results)
    {
        results.Add(Result.Create(...));
    }
});

results = results.Where(t => t.IsValid).ToList(); // NRE here due to t is null!
```

or better

```
var results = new List<Result>();

Parallel.For(0, 100, index =>
{
    var result = Result.Create(...);

    lock (results)
    {
        results.Add(result);
    }
});

results = results.Where(t => t.IsValid).ToList(); // NRE here due to t is null!
```

so that the `result` creation doesn't block the `List<>` writing :-) Otherwise the code is useless and it would be executed sequentially.

Comment: Or simply `var results = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).AsParallel().Select(i => Result.Create(...)).Where(t => t.IsValid).ToList()`

Comment: @sloth Yes, if you are trying to do one of those contests where you have to save on bytes, or you are ranked on obfuscation :-) But I do think there is at least a difference here... `Parallel.For` knows the range of numbers, so it has the `Length` information, while `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).AsParallel()` doesn't know it. I don't know if this information is really used.

Comment: True, you could use `var results = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList().AsParallel()...` to optimize this if needed so the default partitioner could distribute the workload better.

Comment: Locking here essentially converts the code to sequential. Better to use a  ConcurrentQueue<> which doesn't require any locking.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not if `Result.Create` is very slow. The "better" variant only locks on `results.Add`. And for a fast `Result.Create`, the `Parallel.For` is worse than useless

Comment: You might also want to use [ConcurrentBag<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it is optimized for this situation.

Comment: @Caramiriel That is correct... Unless you want to do many read-only operations after the end of the `Parallel.For`, or if you need/want to use an indexer. On writing the `ConcurrentBag<>` is surely many times faster than `lock + List.Add`